# Changing order of integration for products of probability measures

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\nu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ which we define as the product measure $\nu = \xi \otimes \psi$, where $\xi$ and $\psi$ are probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. In terms of integrators we write this as
$$
d\nu(z,x) = d\xi(z) d \psi(x)
$$
Let $f, g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0,\infty)$ be $ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ measurable functions. I would like to know if and under what conditions the following equality folds
\begin{align*}
\int_{A_{z_1,z_2} \times B_{x_1, x_2}} &f(z_1,z_2) g(x_1,x_2) d\nu(z_1,x_1)d\nu(z_2,x_2) \\
&= \int_{A_{z_1 z_2}} f(z_1,z_2) d\xi(z_1) d\xi(z_2) \;  \cdot \; \int_{B_{x_1, x_2}} g(x_1,x_2) d\psi(x_1)d\psi(x_2),
\end{align*}
where the integration variables $(z_1, z_2)$ are values in $A_{z_1, z_2} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and similarly $(x_1,x_2) \in B_{x_1, x_2}$. If we can write
\begin{align}
d\nu(z_1,x_1) d\nu(z_2,x_2)
&= d\xi(z_1) d\xi(z_1)d \psi(x_2) d \psi(x_2)  \label{eq1}\\
&= (\xi \otimes \xi)(dz_1, dz_2) \cdot (\psi \otimes \psi)(dx_1, dx_2) \label{eq2}
\end{align}
I guess the result follows from Fubini's Theorem, but how do I show that $$
d\nu(z_1,x_1) d\nu(z_2,x_2)
= (\xi \otimes \xi)(dz_1, dz_2) \cdot (\psi \otimes \psi)(dx_1, dx_2)
$$
It is enough that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[a_1, b_1] \times [c_1, d_1]} & \int_{[a_2, b_2] \times [c_2, d_2]} d\nu(z_1,x_1)d\nu(z_2,x_2) \\
&= \int_{[a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2]} d \xi(z_1) d\xi(z_2) \cdot \int_{[c_1, d_1] \times [c_2, d_2]} d \psi(x_1) d\psi(x_2)
\end{align*}